# Problems with display resolution

Tags: drivers, 16.04, display, display-resolution

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and I have a problem with the display resolution of my monitor. My monitor can go up to 1440x900, but I am unable to see this option in Displays, with it instead defaulting to 1024x768. I suspected it was a problem with graphical drivers, however, I am almost certain the computer comes with Intel integrated graphics, which should have had drivers installed during the OS install. What steps can I take to possibly solve this problem?

Output from running `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
DeviceName:  Onboard Graphics
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
```

Output from running `grep -E -2 'EE|WW|Modeline|intel' /var/log/Xorg.o.log`

```
[145192.718] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[145192.718] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon May 16 14:23:23 2016
[145193.886] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
--
[145194.132] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[145194.132] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[145194.132] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[145194.132]    Entry deleted from font path.
[145194.132] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[145194.132]    Entry deleted from font path.
[145194.132] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[145194.132]    Entry deleted from font path.
[145194.132] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[145194.132]    Entry deleted from font path.
[145194.132] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[145194.132]    Entry deleted from font path.
[145194.132] (==) FontPath set to:
--
[145194.718]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 9.0
[145194.718] (==) AIGLX enabled
[145194.718] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[145194.718] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 1
[145194.718] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[145194.718] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[145194.718] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[145194.718] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[145194.718] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[145194.745] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[145194.768] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[145194.769]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 2.99.917
[145194.769]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
--
[145195.324]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[145195.324]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[145195.324] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics     Chipsets:
i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G, 915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43

[145195.324] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
[145195.324] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100,   6100
[145195.324] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
[145195.324] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[145195.324] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[145195.324] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[145195.324] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20151010
[145195.324] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.917+git20160325-1ubuntu1 (Timo Aaltonen <tjaalton@debian.org>)
[145195.324] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[145195.324] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[145195.324] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[145195.324] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[145195.324] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
--
[145195.343]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 0.0.2
[145195.343]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[145195.343] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[145195.343] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 2000
[145195.343] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2; using a maximum of 2 threads
[145195.343] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in   Screen section
"Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[145195.343] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[145195.343] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[145195.343] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[145195.344] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 has no monitor section
[145195.344] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VGA1
[145195.344] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 has no monitor section
[145195.344] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI1
[145195.344] (II) intel(0): Output DP1 has no monitor section
[145195.344] (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP1
[145195.344] (--) intel(0): Using a maximum size of 256x256 for hardware cursors
[145195.344] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 has no monitor section
[145195.344] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VIRTUAL1
[145195.344] (--) intel(0): Output VGA1 using initial mode 1024x768 on pipe 0
[145195.344] (==) intel(0): TearFree disabled
[145195.344] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[145195.344] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[145195.344] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
--
[145195.344] (II) Unloading vesa
[145195.345] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[145195.345] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Sandybridge (gen6, gt1) backend
[145195.345] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
[145195.345] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
[145195.345] (II) intel(0): HW Cursor enabled
[145195.345] (II) intel(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[145195.345] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[145195.345] (==) intel(0): Display hotplug detection enabled
[145195.345] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[145195.345] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[145195.345] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl
[145195.345] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 enabled
[145195.345] (II) intel(0): hardware support for Present enabled
[145195.345] (--) RandR disabled
[145195.350] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
--
[145195.358] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized i965
[145195.358] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[145195.360] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1024x768@60.0 on VGA1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[145195.360] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 270 x 203
[145198.876] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[145198.876] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
--
[145198.901] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[145198.902] (II) evdev: ROCCAT ROCCAT Isku FX: initialized for relative axes.
[145198.902] (WW) evdev: ROCCAT ROCCAT Isku FX: ignoring absolute axes.
[145198.902] (**) ROCCAT ROCCAT Isku FX: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[145198.902] (**) ROCCAT ROCCAT Isku FX: (accel) acceleration profile 0
--
[145198.962] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[145198.962] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: initialized for relative axes.
[145198.962] (WW) evdev: Logitech USB Receiver: ignoring absolute axes.
[145198.962] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[145198.962] (**) Logitech USB Receiver: (accel) acceleration profile 0
```

Comment: try to install the drivers manually and see if it works.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: Please edit your question to add output of graphics detection by X:  `grep -E -2  'EE|WW|Modeline|intel' /var/log/Xorg.0.log`